# merge two array into one

Tags: java, algorithm, merge

```
    int [] queue1 = {4,7,2,9,12,35,8,49};
    int [] queue2 = {24,53,6,19,41,71,1,68,11,32,99}        
    int[]mergeQ = new int[queue1.length + queue2.length];

    for(int i=0; i < queue1.length; i++ )
    {

      mergeQ[i*2] = queue1[i];       
      mergeQ[i*2+1] = queue2[i];  
    }
    for(int i=0; i < mergeQ.length; i++) {            
        System.out.print(mergeQ[i]+",");
    }
```

output: 4,24,7,53,2,6,9,19,12,41,35,71,8,1,49,68,0,0,0

how can i print out the rest of elements of queue2.?

Comment: You didn't put in all numbers in `queue2`, so the end of `mergeQ` are 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your merge algorithm makes an assumption that `queue1.length < queue2.length`. Although it is correct for your program, it is not generally a good thing to make such assumptions.

Change the merge algorithm to go through both arrays until you hit the length of the shorter one, then dump the remaining elements of the longer array into the tail of the merged array. You can do it all in a single loop, like this:

```
int p = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i < queue1.length || i < queue2.length ; i++) {
    if (i < queue1.length) {
        mergeQ[p++] = queue1[i];
    }
    if (i < queue2.length) {
        mergeQ[p++] = queue2[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
    int[] queue1 = { 4, 7, 2, 9, 12, 35, 8, 49 };
    int[] queue2 = { 24, 53, 6, 19, 41, 71, 1, 68, 11, 32, 99 };
    int[] mergeQ = new int[queue1.length + queue2.length];

    int dest = 0;
    int src1 = 0;
    int src2 = 0;
    while (src1 < queue1.length || src2 < queue2.length) {
        if (src1 < queue1.length) {
            mergeQ[dest++] = queue1[src1++];
        }
        if (src2 < queue2.length) {
            mergeQ[dest++] = queue2[src2++];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mergeQ.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(mergeQ[i] + ",");
    }
```

This works regardless of whether `queue1` or `queue2` is shorter.

It also preserves the property of your algorithm that elements of the two queues are interleaved. If that's not important, then the whole thing can be replaced by two calls to [`System.arraycopy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there was any order in which you wanted the two queues merged (such as an element from queue one fallowed by an element from queue two) though the fallowing code will place all elements in the merge queue.

```
int [] 
    queue1 = {4,7,2,9,12,35,8,49},
    queue2 = {24,53,6,19,41,71,1,68,11,32,99},
    mergeQ = new int[queue1.length + queue2.length];

for (int i=0; i < queue1.length; i++ )
    mergeQ[i] = queue1[i];

for (int i = 0; i < queue2.length; i++)
    mergeQ[queue1.length + i] = queue2[i];

for(int i=0; i < mergeQ.length; i++)
    System.out.print(mergeQ[i]+",");
```

Comment: Now I feel stupid not asking the question about the order....I agree...This is a much more straightforward method

Comment: That code only copies elements from queue1 due to error in `mergeQ[queue1.length + i] = queue1[i];`

Comment: Fixed. Sorry. It was a simple typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] queue1 = {4,7,2,9,12,35,8,49};
int[] queue2 = {24,53,6,19,41,71,1,68,11,32,99}        
int[] mergeQ = new int[queue1.length + queue2.length

int i=0;
for(; i < queue1.length; i++ ){
  mergeQ[i*2] = queue1[i];       
  mergeQ[i*2+1] = queue2[i];
}
if(queue1.length>queue2.length){ 
 for(int j=i;j<queue1.length;j++)
  mergeQ[j+2] = queue1[j];
}else if(queue1.length<queue2.length){
 for(int j=i;j<queue2.length;j++)
  mergeQ[j+2] = queue2[j];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check which array is longer. Retain a counter for the difference between the two. Changing the code a bit...a little more unorthodox...but a little more clean

```
int [] queue2 = {24,53,6,19,41,71,1,68,11,32,99};

int[]mergeQ = new int[queue1.length + queue2.length];

int larger=queue1.length;
int smaller=queue2.length;

if(queue1.length < queue2.length)
  {
   larger=queue2.length;
   smaller=queue1.length;
  }

    for(int i=0; i < queue1.length; i++ )
    {
      mergeQ[i*2] = queue1[i];       
      mergeQ[i*2+1] = queue2[i];

    }

    for(int i=mergeQ.length; i < queue2.length; i++ )
    {
       mergeQ[i] = queue2[larger-smaller];
       smaller++;
    }

    for(int i=0; i < mergeQ.length; i++){


        System.out.print(mergeQ[i]+",");
    }
```

This should do it for you

Answer (score 0):

Input : {1, 3, 5, 7} and {2, 4, 6}
Output : {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}}

```
        int c[] = {2, 4, 6, 8};
        int n[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
        int f = 0;
        int res[] = new int[c.length + n.length];
        for(int i=0;i<(c.length + n.length); i++)
        {
            if(c.length > n.length)
            {
                if(i<c.length)
                    res[f++] = c[i];
                else if(f<=res.length-1)
                    res[f++] = c[i];

                if(i<n.length)
                res[f++] = (char) n[i];
            }else{
                if(i<n.length)
                    res[f++] = n[i];
                else if(f<=res.length-1)
                    res[f++] = n[i];

                if(i<c.length)
                res[f++] = (char) c[i];
            }

        }
        for(int i=0;i<res.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.print("   "+res[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code dumping is discouraged.  Some explanation on what you did would benefit the OP - especially if he or she is a beginner.  Explanations also discourage simple copying and pasting without understanding what you did.